# Always on top ImageView

Tags: java, android

How can I add an ImageView to my application which is always on top of the app when the application is opened, even though the Activity switched? I don't want to create the button on every single activity.

Comment: You should use fragments in order to do that , With activities you cant's have something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now used this [Chathead](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/) method.

Answer (score 0):

I would use DialogFragment. In dialogFragment layout put ImageView to display your image. It is up to you to implement logic for showing hiding DialogFragment. Also, logic for displaying (downloading maybe) image needs to be implemented in fragment, so your activities remains clean.

To be able to show dialog fragment, every Activity class needs to extend FragmentActivity.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a fragment to avoid adding the button on each activity, but when I implemented floating action button in my app, I found it easier to have a separate layout file with the button, and include that layout file in each activity's content. Then I use a common base class to listen to the button's action.